# create a data model clsss to json in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode

This is the json I got from server I tried to create a data model for this json but didn't get in to success because of nested arrays. can anyone please help in creating data model for this jsonfile in swift. if you need I can provide the the data model I created for this json but that is not working

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "loo_id": null,
      "loo_name": null,
      "loo_address": null,
      "loo_image": null,
      "price": null,
      "loo_location": null,
      "type": null,
      "category": [
        {
          "category_id": "1",
          "category_name": "Hotel",
          "cat_enable_image": "****images/category/hotel_clr.png",
          "cat_disable_image": "****images/category/hotel_gry.png",
          "status": "0"
        },

        {
          "category_id": "5",
          "category_name": "Shopping Mall",
          "cat_enable_image": "****images/category/shopping_mall_clr.png",
          "cat_disable_image": "****images/category/shopping_mall_gry.png",
          "status": "0"
        }
      ],
      "days": null,
      "timings": null,
      "facilities": [
        {
          "facility_category_id": "1",
          "facility_category_name": "Male",
          "facility_category_enable_image": "****images/facility_category/male_clr.png",
          "facility_category_disable_image": "****images/facility_category/male_gry.png",
          "status": "0",
          "facility": [
            {
              "facility_id": "1",
              "facility_name": "Toiletten",
              "enable_image": "****images/facilities/toilet_color.png",
              "disable_image": "****images/facilities/toilet_grey.png",
              "count": "0",
              "status": "0"
            },
            {
              "facility_id": "2",
              "facility_name": "Lavatory",
              "enable_image": "****images/facilities/lavatory_color.png",
              "disable_image": "****images/facilities/lavatory_grey.png",
              "count": "0",
              "status": "0"
            },
            {
              "facility_id": "3",
              "facility_name": "Urinals",
              "enable_image": "****images/facilities/urinals_color.png",
              "disable_image": "****images/facilities/urinals_grey.png",
              "count": "0",
              "status": "0"
            },
            {
              "facility_id": "4",
              "facility_name": "Shower",
              "enable_image": "****images/facilities/shower_color.png",
              "disable_image": "****images/facilities/shower_grey.png",
              "count": "0",
              "status": "0"
            },
            {
              "facility_id": "5",
              "facility_name": "Standing Toilet",
              "enable_image": "****images/facilities/standing_toilet_color.png",
              "disable_image": "****images/facilities/standing_toilet_grey.png",
              "count": "0",
              "status": "0"
            }
          ]
        },
         {
          "facility_category_id": "4",
          "facility_category_name": "Wheelchair",
          "facility_category_enable_image": "****images/facility_category/1771138800.png",
          "facility_category_disable_image": "****images/facility_category/1790222751.png",
          "status": "0",
          "facility": [
            {
              "facility_id": "12",
              "facility_name": "Toiletten",
              "enable_image": "****images/facilities/toilet_color.png",
              "disable_image": "****images/facilities/toilet_grey.png",
              "count": "0",
              "status": "0"
            },
            {
              "facility_id": "13",
              "facility_name": "Lavatory",
              "enable_image": "****images/facilities/lavatory_color.png",
              "disable_image": "****images/facilities/lavatory_grey.png",
              "count": "0",
              "status": "0"
            },
            {
              "facility_id": "14",
              "facility_name": "Shower",
              "enable_image": "****images/facilities/shower_color.png",
              "disable_image": "****images/facilities/shower_grey.png",
              "count": "0",
              "status": "0"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "accessbility": [
        {
          "accessbility_id": "1",
          "accessbility_name": "Wheelchair",
          "accessbility_enable_image": "****images/accessbility/wheelchair_clr.png",
          "accessbility_disable_image": "****images/accessbility/wheelchair_gry.png",
          "status": "0"
        },
        {
          "accessbility_id": "2",
          "accessbility_name": "Car Access",
          "accessbility_enable_image": "****images/accessbility/car_access_clr.png",
          "accessbility_disable_image": "****images/accessbility/car_access_gry.png",
          "status": "0"
        }
      ],
      "terms_conditions": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This will help: https://quicktype.io/

Comment: Thanks bro.you saved  a lot of my time

Comment: @FaysalAhmed this is an awesome tool. Did not know about it. Saves a lot of typing time.

Comment: can I pass swiftyjson object to it.

Comment: @SHINTOJOSEPH What do you want?

Comment: can I pass swifyjson object to it